# TensorFlow 1.2.1 and InceptionV3 to classify an image

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, coreml

I'm trying to create an example using the Keras built in the latest version of TensorFlow from Google. This example should be able to classify a classic image of an elephant. The code looks like this:

```
# Import a few libraries for use later
from PIL import Image as IMG

from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions


# Get a copy of the Inception model
print('Loading Inception V3...\n')
model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
print ('Inception V3 loaded\n')

# Read the elephant JPG
elephant_img = IMG.open('elephant.jpg')

# Convert the elephant to an array
elephant = image.img_to_array(elephant_img)
elephant = preprocess_input(elephant)

elephant_preds = model.predict(elephant)

print ('Predictions: ', decode_predictions(elephant_preds))
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error when trying to evaluate the model with model.predict:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (299, 299, 3)
```

This code is taken from and based on [the excellent example coremltools-keras-inception](https://github.com/vml-ffleschner/coremltools-keras-inception-test) and will be expanded more when it is figured out.

Comment: Could you please share the entire traceback?

Comment: I can throw it in for reference if you still want but the answer explains what happened and I mentioned exactly which line failed.

Comment: I see now you posted an answer, good job, ignore my last :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this error occured is that model always expects the **batch** of examples - not a **single** example. This diverge from a common understanding of models as mathematical functions of their inputs. The reasons why model expects batches are:

1. Models are computationaly designed to work faster on batches in order to speed up training.
2. There are algorithms which takes into account the batch nature of input (e.g. [**Batch Normalization**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) or **GAN** training tricks).

So four dimensions comes from a first dimension which is a **sample / batch** dimension and then - the next 3 dimensions are image dims.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found the answer.  Even though the documentation states that if the top layer is included the shape of the input vector is still set to take a batch of images.  Thus we need to add this before the code line for the prediction:

```
elephant = numpy.expand_dims(elephant, axis=0)
```

Then the tensor is in the right shape and everything works correctly. I am still uncertain why the documentation states that the input vector should be (3x299x299) or (299x299x3) when it clearly wants 4 dimensions.

Be careful!